# Autocad start drawing away from the Z=0 (non-coplanar)

Tags: autocad, technical-drawing, drawings

I'm having an issue when I draw some elements. They are been drawn away from the Z=0, is causing to be non-coplanar with other elements. So, I cannot make fillets or can find crossing points. I don't want to keep flatten them or setting Z=0 manually. Does anyone know how to start drawing in Z=0 by default? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the AutoCAD shall start at the origin point (x = 0, y = 0, z = 0), unless you are using "user coordinate system (UCS)" defined by the previous user. You can delete or modify UCS by following the steps indicated in [this article](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-map-3d/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/MAP3D-Use/files/GUID-03FD8FD5-C942-4934-B465-8D96718DB87E-htm.html#:%7E:text=Click%20Map%20Setup%20tab%20Coordinate%20System%20panel%20Coordinate,modify%20a%20default%20coordinate%20system%2C%20duplicate%20it%20first.).

Or as others have indicated, you might need to redefine the "Snap" command features.

Answer (score 0):

Two thing to look at.

The first is your coordinate system.  World coordinate system uses elevation 0 by default.  Any line started not connected to anything will be drawing to elevation zero.

The second issue is if you have pre-existing line work like say a survey whose contours wer placed into the drawing with their respective Z elevations maintained.  Same goes for road geometry and control line as they may already have existing elevations attached to them.  There is a setting you can change called OSNAPZ.  At the command prompt type in the following:

```
OSNAPZ 1
```

You can read up a bit more on an article [here](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/civil-3d-forum/osnapz-1/td-p/5120618).  I am not sure if its still an issue gtting it to stick or if you have to do it every time.

As for picting intersect points, you can use apparent intersect instead of intersect.  It will grab the visible intersection point based on your current view.